# Android dependencies : apklib vs aar files

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-maven-plugin, apklib, aar

From my understanding, `apklib` contains code + resource shared with `Maven` .
`aar` files are distributed by `Gradle`.

The `aar` differ from apklib in one major way : classes are compiled and included in a classes.jar in the root of the aar. Whereas `apklib` cannot contain compiled class files or jars.

1 Can somebody explain the main differences between `apklib` vs `aar` files ?

2 Can `Maven` use `aar` ? Can `Gradle` use `apklib` ?

3 Which format is "better" ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> 1 Can somebody explain the main differences between apklib vs aar
>   files ?

Couple differences that come to my mind, in addition to the ones you mentioned

1. `aar` doesn't contain source code
2. `aar` can contain custom proguard file and custom lint rules

> 2 Can Maven use aar ? Can Gradle use apklib ?

The Android Maven Plugin supports `aar` since version 3.7.0.
Gradle doesn't support using `apklib` dependencies but you could export your `android-library` as `apklib` (see [this post](https://plus.google.com/+ChristopherBroadfoot/posts/7uyipf8DTau)).

Comment: Also apklib is deprecated in the android-maven-plugin since its VERY old and predates aar and other formats and only ever worked with the maven tooling.