# android studio import maven project without gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle

i try include aacdecoder (https://github.com/vbartacek/aacdecoder-android) to my project. In decoder readme says my dependency is

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.spoledge.aacdecoder</groupId>
        <artifactId>aacdecoder-lib</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

but when i use in my build.gradle like this

```
compile 'com.spoledge.aacdecoder:aacdecoder-lib:0.8'
```

it fail when i am try sync it.

---

After jitpack.io (thanks OleGG), like in image (downside) it isnt apper like exoplayer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from maven library definition, it's distributed as `<type>apklib</type>`, and apklib is unsupported by Gradle.

The easiest solution will be to package this library within your repo. Also you can follow the instructions from this question [How to convert apklib to aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924504/how-to-convert-apklib-to-aar), but anyway it'll lead to app repackage.

Also you can try to use https://jitpack.io to package it automatically. In this case you need to add jitpack repo to your root `build.gradle` file like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and then provide github repo as a dependency in appropriate modules:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.vbartacek:aacdecoder-android:0.8'
}
```

Comment: thanks it is work but how can i import in my class because this is work     import com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer; but i cant use import com.github or com.spoledge. They dont come after com.

Comment: Possibly, jitpack was unable to convert github repo to archive. So, we are back to situation when you need to make library manually