# Android Studio 2.2: Integration of the ImmobilienScout24 Rest API from Github

Tags: java, android, maven, sdk

I am in need of some serious help. 
I have this project where I need to Import/ export stuff from the is24-api-android-sdk that can be found on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/ImmobilienScout24/is24-api-android-sdk)). I opened up a new application with a blank activity for starters. Then downloaded the zip file. I unpacked it and tried to add the sdk via import module but it always wants me to specify the gradle or android eclipse project but there are no gradle files. I also tried to add it via maven or compile the dependency straight on but i find no information how to do this that way.

I'm just stuck big time and not sure how to help myself. Is there any instructions or help you can give me.

Comment: Which project did you choose to import from that zip file?

Comment: @Bexx Could this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924504/how-to-convert-apklib-to-aar

Comment: @Krish the RestApiSdk project

Comment: @Bexx  Ok, that project is not android studio project . So you should import that as a eclipse project.For that you have to follow this steps: File->New->New Module->Import Eclipse ADT Project->Next->and select RestApiSdk project .It will work.

Comment: @Krish that worked. and how do i add it to my app since it is now imported but i cannot use it

Comment: If you add it as a module you can simply use it like a library project.

Comment: @Krish i always get this error when i try to get the provided lines of code from the github Read Me page to work 'dependency on module restApiSdk'

error: Error:Dependency IS24Application:restApiSdk:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: /Users/Rebecca/Desktop/IS24Application/restApiSdk/build/outputs/apk/restApiSdk-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: add the module dependency to your project by adding it is gradle file.